# Information from API - JSON

Tags: android, arrays, json

I try to get information from this [link](http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/?format=json)

and I don't get it !

This is my code:

```
    String s = getJSONFile();
    String myDataArray[] = {};

    try{
        JSONObject reportJSON = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray dateJSON = reportJSON.getJSONArray("terrestrial_date");

        myDataArray = new String[dateJSON.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i <dateJSON.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject = dateJSON.getJSONObject(i);
            myDataArray[i] = jsonObject.getString("terrestrial_date");
        }
}catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> stringAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, myDataArray);
    if (mListView != null){
        mListView.setAdapter(stringAdapter);
    }
}
```

this is the getJSONFile method:

```
public String getJSONFile() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.weather_json);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: where is your getJson() method

Comment: Have you seen the value of `reportJSON`?

Comment: this is  the method:  public String getJSONFile(){
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.weather_json);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

Comment: Do you want to parse this json?

Comment: yes.. I need to parse Json

Comment: @Bon please debug your code and you'd realise your mistake in a second.

Comment: Do you have json file in your raw folder?

Comment: yes I have the json file..

Answer (score 0):

You should use GSON librari and for the Model of this code http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

This is so easy.

Answer (score 0):

`terrstial_date` is a `String` of report. try this,

```
String date=jsonObject.getString("terestial_date");
```

also your `json` parsing structere is not correct accroding to your `json`

```
{
"report": {
    "terrestrial_date": "2017-10-13",
    "sol": 1844,
    "ls": 73.0,
    "min_temp": -81.0,
    "min_temp_fahrenheit": -113.8,
    "max_temp": -28.0,
    "max_temp_fahrenheit": -18.4,
    "pressure": 869.0,
    "pressure_string": "Higher",
    "abs_humidity": null,
    "wind_speed": null,
    "wind_direction": "--",
    "atmo_opacity": "Sunny",
    "season": "Month 3",
    "sunrise": "2017-10-13T10:59:00Z",
    "sunset": "2017-10-13T22:43:00Z"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing in wrong way

**1.`report`** is a `JsonObject` inside your `response` means you have your **`report`** inside another `JsonObject`. First you have to parse your response to get **`report`** data

**2.`terrestrial_date`** is a `string` data so you have to use `report.getJsonString("terrestrial_date")` you are using `reportJSON.getJSONArray("terrestrial_date");` which is used for `Array` data

For, more information get a look here **[How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/7073808)**

Try this,

```
String s = getJSONFile();
String terrestrial_date = "";

     try{
        JSONObject responce = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONObject report= responce.getJSONObject("report");
        terrestrial_date = report.getString("terrestrial_date");

        }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**EDIT**

Try, **`Volley`** for fetching `JSON` data

**First** you need to add dependency of volley in `build.gradle` file-:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Then use following code to fetch or parse your `JSON` data

```
// Tag used to cancel the request

String url = "http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/?format=json";


StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        String terrestrial_date = "";

                       try{
                          JSONObject responce = new JSONObject(response);
                          JSONObject report= responce.getJSONObject("report");
                          terrestrial_date = report.getString("terrestrial_date");

                       }catch (JSONException e){
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    }
                });


    // Adding request to request queue
Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(strReq);
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

As, You can see the screenshot above. I am getting response with the same code

Comment: @Bon try this may help you

Comment: Are you sure you are getting this response in your Android

Comment: yes i try now, and my debug is: "Cannot resolve symbol reportJSON

Comment: ohh sorry that was typo mistake

Comment: check updated answer or replase reportJson with responce

Comment: you need to change that line to JSONObject report= responce.getJSONObject("report");

Comment: sorry but still not work to me, I do all the suggested in posts here, and nothing work to me, I dont know what do to.. I do this with Volley vs oKHTTP and etc.. I post again my last code that I do now, if you can tell me what I wrong I am very  Appreciate it!

Comment: @Bon see the screenshot above. can you please put your complete class in your question'

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get response from [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/?format=json")
  .get()
  .build();

try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String json = response.body().string();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject reportJson =  jsonObject.getJSONObject("report"); // your report object.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your Json file in your assets folder with .json extension and use this method to get JsonString from it

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset(String fileName) {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open(fileName);

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }
```

And get the String using this function like this

```
String jsonString = MyApplication.loadJSONFromAsset(this,"yourJsonFileName.json");
```

and Parse like that

```
try{
        JSONObject responce = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray report= responce.getJSONObject("report");
        String terrestrial_date = report.getString("terrestrial_date");

}catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code after all the change:

```
  public void find_weather() {
    String url = "http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/?format=json";

    JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject main_object = response.getJSONObject("results");
                JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("");
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);
                String date = object.getString("date");
                String tempMin = String.valueOf(main_object.getDouble("min_temp"));
                String tempMax = String.valueOf(main_object.getDouble("max_temp"));
                String atmo_opacity = object.getString("atmo_opacity");

                mMaxTemp.setText("max_temp");
                mMinTemp.setText("min_temp");
                mAtmoOpacity.setText("atmo_opacity");

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-MM-dd");
                String formatted_data = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
                mDate.setText(formatted_data);

                double temp_max_int = Double.parseDouble(tempMax);
                double temp_min_int = Double.parseDouble(tempMin);

                mMaxTemp.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                mMinTemp.setText(String.valueOf(i));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(jor);
```